# Prevent Inno Setup deleting some files on uninstall

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation

Well, that actual question is already described in the title. I want to prevent Inno Setup uninstall from deleting **log** and **config** files that are stored in `program installation` directory. I know this is a bad practice. Normally I should use per-user directories and store all personal data there.

However this is a special case. The program I am working with, is a wrapper for a very old application. This old app has a lot of paths hard-coded into it and I need it to reside on `C:\` and also to keep **logs** in the same directory as executables. Anyway, the whole setup is a bit messy.

Is there an easy way to selectively delete files/folders during uninstall?
Can I prevent some of them from being deleted?

Comment: `Flags: uninsneveruninstall` for files that you install, but want to leave after deinstallation. All files that would be created by app itself AFTER installation will not be deleted during deinstallation - unless you would program that in the script.

Comment: Yep, that helps, could you post this as an answer, I will then mark it solved

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`Flags: uninsneveruninstall`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection) for files that you install, but want/need to leave after deinstallation.

All files that would be created by Application itself AFTER  the installation will not be deleted during deinstallation - unless you would program that in your installation script.

Comment: My app is deployed to the directory that the user selects. I have a file that I wish to preserve, after the app is uninstalled. What do I need to add in my setup manifest? thanks

Comment: `[Files] Source: "C:\My_Setup_Files\FileIwantToKeep.ext"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: uninsneveruninstall onlyifdoesntexist` - first flag marks not to delete during uninstall, second flag points not to overwrite during reinstallation if file exists after previous version.

Comment: In my case onlyifdoesntexist is not doing anything in my manifest (Inno v 5.5.4(a).